# When do resource nodes respawn?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I know that resource nodes are individually instanced per player. However, I'm unsure what determines when the same resource nodes will respawn for any given player. I know they don't reset based on zoning in and out of an area, as I've tried that (and it would likely be easily exploitable). As such, I'm would like to know the following:

- Is it based on a set length of time. and if so, how long is that length of time?
- Does the quality of the node matter, like whether it is "Rich" or not?
- Does the level of the node matter? For example, will Copper nodes respawn faster than say, Mithril nodes?

Comment: I noticed that the rich ores seem to always be in the same places that I've encountered them (usually in the back of a cave of location that hold lots of enemies).

Comment: Do note: Resource nodes on the overflow server and standard server are not shared.

Comment: @Domocus So If I clear a map area on Overflow then Queue up to the regular map I get a while new set of nodes?

Comment: @Emerica. yes indeed. So do chests :)

Comment: @Rodolfo This is very awesome information. Now if only Jute Scraps had nodes...

Answer (score 8):

Resource nodes seem to work in three seperate ways.

1. There are what the devs call "Node farms", groups of 8-10 of the same resource in a small area. These respawn after 23 hours (so people who play at roughly the same time don't have to worry about being a few minutes ahead of 24 hours). These are mostly or entirely food items.
2. There are what I'm going to call "Placed Nodes" which are specifically located, normally rich nodes guarded by veteran or champion enemies, or requiring the completion of an event to access. These also appear to respawn after 23 hours.
3. There are what I'm going to call "wild nodes", located randomly in the wilderness. Most nodes fall under this category. These nodes do not respawn after 23 hours. Instead, wild nodes appear and disappear gradually over time. After a few hours of play, you can return to  an area that was previously cleared and see plenty of nodes. Those are wild nodes. however, you will notice that they are not in exactly the same location as the nodes you previously cleared, as they are different nodes that appears, just in similar locations. This means that an area will gradually become more and more abundant overtime, until all the old nodes you harvested are removed and replaced by newer, full ones. I believe that it takes between 8-24 hours for an area to fully replenish its wild node density. However, a new node can appear on your map within a few minutes of harvesting a nearby node.

Comment: I'm not sure your "Wild" nodes are actually random. Off the top of my head, every time you enter Bloodtide coast, go straight south and you'll find 3 nodes in the lake - 2 iron, and 1 gold.

Comment: I don't think he meant random in the truest sense of the word. I'm pretty sure there are some 'wild' nodes that are a specific resource in a specific spot, whereas the rest have a chance at appearing in any number of set places.

Comment: I haven't run into any "Wild" nodes that are ALWAYS in that spot, but I wouldn't be surprised if that was the case. If it was they are really a fourth category somewhere in-between wild and placed (As they are located in wild areas but permanently placed). Overall I think this still does a good job of explaining the general system.

Comment: They changed it a bit in the last update. This forum post can further explain: https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/support/bugs/Ori-nodes-not-showing-up-as-minable-Friend-showed-me-spawns-I-see-a-ruined-base-like-I-mined-it-but-I-haven-t-can-mine-2-out-of-5/page/5#post388572

Comment: Basically placed nodes and node farms are the same, but the way wild nodes work is more consistent, and they respawn less often.